# Display HTML content on top of silverlight app

Tags: html, silverlight

Is it possible to display HTML content (for instance in a DIV) on top of a Silverlight app? no problem if it needs to be windowless but I want program to be fullscreen. In fact I have a full screen silvleright application (VS2010,C#), and I need to display a small html content in middle of my program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can like this

```
<div id="silverlightcontrol"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#content{position:absolute; top:50%; left:50%; width:300px; height:300px; margin:-150px 0 0 -150px;}
#silverlightcontrol{position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; left:0px; top:0px;}
```